# Upgrading from 32-bit Jenkins 2.227 to 64-bit Jenkins 2.235.3?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-update

I have a 32-bit Jenkins build server running version 2.227 that I would like to upgrade to 64-bit, so I am starting by upgrading to the first 64-bit version.  I have performed these steps:

1. Safely shut down Jenkins and disable Windows service; set startup type to disabled.
2. Backed up the entire `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins` folder.
3. Downloaded JDK 2.245.3 https://archives.jenkins-ci.org/windows-stable/2.235.3/
4. Installed Jenkins version 2.245.3 with the windows installer.  This created the C:\Program Files\Jenkins folder: https://archives.jenkins-ci.org/windows-stable/2.235.3/
5. Copied over the config files from the old install to the new install: All Jenkins/*.xml, fingerprints/, nodes/, userContent/, jobs/, plugins/, secrets/
6. At this point, I noticed that it picked up on the wrong java version, so I copied the Java 11 JDK to C:\Program Files
7. Modified the JDK version to Java 11 in jenkins.xml and config.xml
8. Modified the Jenkins version to 2.235.3 in config.xml

After following those steps, I started up the Jenkins service and went to its URL but it presented the initial setup screen.  I followed the steps and on the Jenkins page, it did not have any of the previous builds - as if it was a fresh install, despite copying over the config files.

Are there any established steps to upgrade from 32 to 64-bit Jenkins or otherwise anything that I missed here?  I have not seen any official documentation on this, just generic install docs that I have been following:

- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/platform-information/upgrade-java-to-11/
- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.235/
- https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/02/01/windows-installers/
- To know which files to copy to the new Jenkins install: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins